# add key and value in json file using javascript

Tags: javascript, json, lodash

the data.json look like

```
 [
     {
         "uid": 11111,
         "status": "ADMIN"
     },
     {
         "uid": 22222
     } 
 ]
```

i use lodash for find the key uid = 22222

> _.find(data, (item)=>item.uid === 22222)

the result is {uid: 22222}

how can i add some status: "value" in result that i find by lodash
i expect like this

```
[
     {
         "uid": 11111,
         "status": "ADMIN"
     },
     {
         "uid": 22222,
         "status": "USER"
     } 
 ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gives you the object, so you can just work with it directly:

```
_.find(data, item => item.uid === 22222).status = "USER";
```

Otherwise you can get the index and update the entire object.

```
const idx = _.findIndex(data, item => item.uid === 22222);
data[idx] = Object.assign(data[idx], {status: "USER"});
```

Depending on the environment you're working in, you don't need to use lodash and you can just use `data.find`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `_.find()` to get the object, and `_.set()` to update it:

```js
var data = [{"uid":11111,"status":"ADMIN"},{"uid":22222}];

_.set(_.find(data, function(obj) { return obj.uid === 22222; }), 'value', 'USER');

_.set(_.find(data, function(obj) { return obj.uid === 23322; }), 'value', 'USER'); // no object was found and nothing changed
  
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need lodash, use [Array.prototype.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?v=control):

```
var arr = [
  {
    "uid": 11111,
    "status": "ADMIN"
  },
  {
    "uid": 22222
  } 
]

// get correct item in array
var item = arr.find(i => i.uid === 22222)
// object is mutable, array have a pointer to the object
item.status = 'USER'

console.log(arr)
```

[Here is a jsbin to play around.](http://jsbin.com/siwusim/edit?js,console)

If you are in an old environment ([Internet Explorer mostly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?v=control#Browser_compatibility)), use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=control):

```
// will be undefined if not found, so check for that
var item = arr.filter(i => i.uid === 22222)[0]
```